# The log K value for Cr-EDTA complex is 23, still Cr(III) cannot be titrated directly

Tags: experimental-chemistry, analytical-chemistry

It's related to stability constants.
I don't get the question and where is it taking and wanting to answer.

Comment: Be aware, for your future posts, that length of the post converging to zero means probability of obtaining answer is converging to zero as well.

Comment: Same question posted 6 years ago: https://www.chemicalforums.com/index.php?topic=91107.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where the equilibrium lays and how fast the system gets there are two independent things.

Many chromium(III) complexes are kinetically stable, slow to be formed or changed. This is not addressed by reaction thermodynamics (like the complex stability constant), but by reaction kinetics.

That is the reason why it cannot be titrated directly. Cr-EDTA complex is not being formed quickly enough to perform titration. Metalochrome indicators would signal a false titration end as much of $\ce{Cr^3+(aq)}$ would stay not reacted with EDTA yet.

Sometimes, the chromium(III) salt solutions have to be boiled for the complex formation reaction to occur.